# python-otter documentation

Tags: python, topsy

I want to collect old tweets for a specific period. I have found out that topsy provides the Otter API to do that. I am developing in Python so I found the python-otter API http://otterapi.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/. However, there is no documentation and I have no idea how to use it! Does anybody know if there is any documention at all. And btw is there another way I can find old tweets programatically?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you diving into the guts of the SVN repository? Why not look at the project page?

Comment: But I did that. There is no documentation there!

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/otterapi/ seems to have plenty of documentation...

Comment: I saw that page but there is no documentation for the Python bindings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation can be found in http://code.google.com/p/otterapi/wiki/Resources

Why not directly make GET requests using urllib2 and the like??